# line-by-line or named variable memory profiling in python

Tags: python, memory-leaks, profiling

I am looking for a memory profiler which shows memory usage per line or per variable.

I tried with `memory-profiler`, which shows memory usage per line but the problem is it does not work in ipython environment.

I tried `pympler`, which have a `track_class` and `track_object` function. But they can not track variable type like `list` or `dict` but predefined class or object.
While trying to track list, I got following error:

```
TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'list' object
```

I tried `objgraph`, which shows the type of variables but not pin point the variable. So there may be several `list`, but show output like this:

```
objgraph.show_growth(limit=3) 
tuple                  5228     +5228
function               1330     +1330
wrapper_descriptor      967      +967
```

How can I track variables (not predefined class object) or show memory usage per line in ipython environment?